# Youtube player API: video becomes inaudible after few seconds

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm using youtube player API in android to embed videos in my APP. Everything works fine except a particular video, which becomes inaudible after few seconds (volume is full). The video becomes audible when earphones are plugged in. The video is also audible on youtube as well as the webclient counterpart of the app which I developed.

```
//code sample
youtubeFragment.initialize(BuildConfig.ApiKey, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            youtubePlayer.cueVideo(TestDataDetail.getInstance().getYoutubeVideoLink(), youtubeStartTime);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {
            try {
               Logger.INSTANCE.d(TAG, "Youtube error:001" + errorReason.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               Logger.INSTANCE.e("onError", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Logger.INSTANCE.d(TAG, "Youtube initialization :000" + youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
    });
```